# Java - while loop expressions

Tags: java

I am wondering why one loop works while the other doesn't even though they are very similar.

The `dmCyl` loop I would like to loop until a positive int is entered. This is the loop that does not work. However, the `hgtCyl` loop, which loops until the user enters an int, does work. It seems like the `(dmCyl < 0)` loop is just completely ignored. Why is that?

Also, the loop that works does so whether I put `hgtCyl = scnr.nextInt();` in the while body `(after scnr.next())` or outside of it. Does it's location change anything?

Thanks!

EDIT: 
Setting the first while to a do while loop solves the problem.
Thanks again!
Solution:

```
dmCyl = scnr.nextInt();

    do{
        System.out.print("please insert positive int");
         dmCyl = scnr.nextInt();
    }while (dmCyl < 0);
```

Original Code:

```
int dmCyl = 0;
int hgtCyl = 0;

Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

while (dmCyl < 0) {
    System.out.print("Please enter an integer");
    scnr.next();
}

dmCyl = scnr.nextInt();
```

And the loop that works:

```
while (!scnr.hasNextInt()){
    System.out.print("Please enter an integer");
    scnr.next();
}

hgtCyl = scnr.nextInt();
```

Comment: As a rule 0 is never less than 0. So your first loop exits immediately.

Comment: or what is the value of `dmCyl` when entering the loop (and testing `dmCyl < 0` for the first time)

Comment: `(dmCyl < 0)` is `0 < 0`, which is always false.

Comment: BTW, in your `dmCyl < 0` loop you are never changing the value of `dmCyl`, so if the loop is entered it will never exit.

Comment: Why does placing "dmCyl = scnr.nextInt();" before the while loop not fix it then? Wouldn't dmCyl be the user input and not 0 then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use do/while

```
do {
    System.out.print("Please enter an integer");
    dmCyl = scnr.nextInt();
} while (dmCyl < 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `dmCyl` to zero initially then you are telling the loop to only go while it is less than zero. Since at the point it starts the loop it has already satisfied the condition and never enters the loop. Set `dmCyl` equal to -1 instead.

Answer (score 1):

You initialize `dmCyl = 0`, so your statement `dmCyl < 0` is false.. you should try to add something like this: `while (dmcyl <= 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Here part of the official description of `while` from the [Java Language Specification 14.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.12), relevant text marked (bold) by me:

> **A while statement is executed by first evaluating the Expression.** If the result is of type Boolean, it is subject to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
>
> If evaluation of the Expression or the subsequent unboxing conversion (if any) completes abruptly for some reason, the while statement completes abruptly for the same reason.
>
> Otherwise, execution continues by making a choice based on the resulting value:
>
> - If the value is true, then the contained Statement is executed. Then there is a choice:
>
>   - If execution of the Statement completes normally, then the entire while statement is executed again, beginning by re-evaluating the Expression.
>   - If execution of the Statement completes abruptly, see §14.12.1.
>
> **If the** (possibly unboxed) **value of the Expression is false, no further action is taken and the while statement completes normally.**

That means, the expression is checked **before** executing the loop content for the first time. If it results in `false` the content is not executed and the loop terminated.